# Combine grep and sub in a single pass?

Tags: r, regex, replace

I wonder if there is a more efficient way to extract `p` and `r` than `grep` and then `sub`:

```
v <- c("a","b","P:18.18% R:66.67%","d")
pr <- grep("^P:([^%]*)% R:([^%]*)%$",v,value=TRUE)
(p <- as.numeric(sub("^P:([^%]*)% R:([^%]*)%$","\\1",pr)))
[1] 18.18
(r <- as.numeric(sub("^P:([^%]*)% R:([^%]*)%$","\\2",pr)))
[1] 66.67
```

Comment: Can there be multiple valid strings in the vector `v`?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein: no; that would be a data error (checked for with `stopifnot`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract both substrings with `gregexpr` and `regmatches`:

```
regmatches(v, gregexpr("(?<=(P|R):).+?(?=%( |))", v, perl = TRUE))


[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "18.18" "66.67"

[[4]]
character(0)
```

You can create a single vector containing all results with `unlist`.

```
unlist(regmatches(v, gregexpr("(?<=(P|R):).+?(?=%( |))", v, perl = TRUE)))

[1] "18.18" "66.67"
```

Comment: this still scans `v` twice, rigth?

Comment: @sds I suppose `gregexpr` scans `v` once.

Comment: ... and then `regmatches` does it again (but yes, the _matching_ happens just once!)

Comment: @sds `regmatches` extracts the substrings at the positions returned by `gregexpr`.